# Connect to WinSCP with private key and private key pass using Python Pysftp

Tags: python, sftp, private-key, winscp

I'm trying to connect to SFTP server.
When I use WinSCP application directly with login, password, host and private key it works perfectly.
But I want to write a script which will download some data every day.

```
import pysftp as sftp

Hostname = "some_host"
username = "user"
password = "password"
privateKey = "path to key"


with sftp.Connection(host=Hostname, port=22, username=username, password=password, private_key=privateKey,  private_key_pass=password) as sftp:
    print("Connection successfully established ... ")
    sftp.listdir()
```

and I have

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

I've tried this on pysftp 0.2.8 and pysftp 0.2.9.
I have private key in .ppk format but also tried to convert it into .pem but this didn't help.

Please help o(^_^)o

Comment: Check [pysftp AuthenticationException while connecting to server with private key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34097068/10824407).

Comment: I've tried the 'solution' from there and it didn't help.

Comment: *"It didn't help"* doesn't help us much with identifying the problem. Post Paramiko log file + Log file of WinSCP showing a successful authentication to the same server from the same local machine using the same credentials. + Your question title is wrong. You are not *"Connecting to WinSCP"*.